# Best model for an NIO implementation?

Tags: java, nio

I'm in the process of converting our java code to use NIO, but I'm not sure of the best way to design it.

My initial approach was to create a pool of selector threads. The threads are started/killed as needed, and channels are registered to a selector thread when they are connected/accepted in a round-robin fashion. From there, each thread blocks on select(), and when woken up will run the appropriate callback associated with each channel that has a selected key.

In addition to this "multiple selector thread" design, I've also seen people say to use a single selector thread, and a pool of dispatch threads. When an IO operation is ready to be performed, the selector notifies a dispatcher thread, which then processes the request. This model has the benefit of not blocking the IO thread, but now we're forcing all of the IO into a single thread and dealing with synchronization/an event queue in the dispatcher.

Additionally I wouldn't be able to use a single direct byte buffer for reading each channel, passing it directly into the callback. Instead I'd have to copy the data out each time a read occurs into an array and reset. (I think..)

What's the best way to implement this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at the **Reactor Pattern**

http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/cpjslides/nio.pdf

How you want your selectors to work really depends on your usecase. (Number of connections, message size, etc)

What is the problem that you are trying to solve by converting from IO to NIO?

Comment: Performance and scalability. A lot fewer threads, and it should simplify our design.

Comment: The Reactor Pattern is a very good choice. There are some implementations of this design that use multiple threads for handling the I/O events. These designs are bad and defeat the purpose of non-blocking asynchronous I/O. When writing a design for high-performance and scalable servers you want to use asynchronous I/O calls and keep all of it on one thread - the `Selector` thread.

Answer (score 3):

You really should look into Mina,

http://mina.apache.org/

It solves all the problems you mentioned.

Comment: Yes although it is a good idea to try and understand what is going on under the covers.

Comment: That's exactly what I did. I didn't really use Mina in my project but I learned a lot from reading their implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Also have a look at [netty](http://netty.io) which is really fast and feature rich and also is used in big systems and by big companies like Redhat (jboss), Twitter, Facebook... .